# Write a R function GroupSummary(x) that will display the five-number summary for two separate groups from a vector x

Tags: r, function, tapply, aggregate

I ran this:

```
GroupSummary <- function(x){
    for (i in x) {
        if(i>0){
            p <-c(summary(x))
            r <- c(p)
        } else {if(i<0){
                n <-c(summary(x))
                r <- c(n)
            } else {stop}
        }
        return(r)
    }
}

x <- c(-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
GroupSummary(x)
```

i end up getting this as a result:

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -10.00   -5.25    0.00    0.00    5.25   10.00
```

I am trying to seperate it in two groups one group for positive numbers and another for negative numbers not combine both.Where did i go wrong in the coding i wrote??  Any hints or help are welcome thank you

Comment: Why not use `fivenum`?

Comment: There are many syntactical problems with your code. For example, (1) The loop is unnecessary; you want to subset your data rather than loop through it (like `x[x>0]` and `x[x<0]`). (2) `i` is an iteration value not the value itself; so a statement like `if(i>0)` is asking whether the iteration of the loop is greater than zero, but you want to check `if(x[i]>0)`. `return(r)` should be outside of the loop, because it will simply return the result of the first iteration. (4) `stop` is used improperly; you probably mean `break`. (5) the `c()` in `c(summary(x))` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the built-in `fivenum`, you can obtain:

```
tapply(x,x>0,fivenum)
```

Comment: u mean instead of using summary(x)  i replace it with tapply(x,x>0,fivenum) ?

Comment: `fivenum` is a built-in function that provides the five number summary that you are trying to obtain. `tapply` applies a function (like `fivenum`, `summary`, etc.) to a vector (your `x`) broken out by subgroups (in this example, the values of `x` greater than and less than 0). Take a look at `? tapply` for more details on how to use it.

Comment: Thank you that was so helpful

Answer (score 1):

May advocate for `aggregate`?

```
> x <- c(-(1:10),1:10)

> aggregate(x, by=list(positive=x>0), summary)
  positive x.Min. x.1st Qu. x.Median x.Mean x.3rd Qu. x.Max.
1    FALSE -10.00     -7.75    -5.50  -5.50     -3.25  -1.00
2     TRUE   1.00      3.25     5.50   5.50      7.75  10.00

> aggregate(x, by=list(positive=x>0), fivenum)
  positive   x.1   x.2   x.3   x.4   x.5
1    FALSE -10.0  -8.0  -5.5  -3.0  -1.0
2     TRUE   1.0   3.0   5.5   8.0  10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be the required function. It works by default for negative/positive, but you can use any index (the default ind=NULL create the positive/negative index). The vectors `x` and `ind` must have the same length, so we stop the execution if this condition doesn't hold (using `stop`).

```
    groupSummary = function(x, ind=NULL) {
      if(is.null(ind)) {
        ind = character(length(x))
        ind[x>=0] = "positive"
        ind[x<0] = "negative"    
      }
      if(length(x)!=length(ind)) stop("'x' and 'ind' must have the same length.")
      out = do.call(rbind, tapply(x,INDEX=ind,FUN=summary))
      return(out)
    }

groupSummary(x)

         Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
negative  -10   -7.75   -5.5 -5.5   -3.25   -1
positive    1    3.25    5.5  5.5    7.75   10


set.seed(123) # to get the same output for 'colors' index
colors = sample(c("red", "blue", "green"), length(x), replace=TRUE)
groupSummary(x, colors)

      Min. 1st Qu. Median    Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
blue    -9   -5.00     -1 -3.0000     0.0    1
green  -10   -6.50     -4 -0.9091     5.0   10
red     -3   -0.75      4  3.1670     6.5    9

groupSummary(x, ind=1:3)
Error in groupSummary(x, ind = 1:3) : 
  'x' and 'ind' must have the same length.
```